# Group by user in nested object mongoose

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, mongodb-query

I want to build a query which gives me the output like

```
{
"idOfUser":[Array of missions],
"idOfUser":[Array of mission]
}
```

actually to group the missions by user which exist on the planning

Each User is assigned one mission and for planning there can be lot of mission in one planning.

what i have already done is

```
if (data["date"]) {
            Planning.find({ start: { $eq: new Date(Number(data["date"])) } }).populate('mission').exec((err, doc) => {
                if (!err)
                    return response(res, doc)
                else
                    return throwError(err, 404, next)
            })
}
```

which gives me the output like

```
{ 
start:"some date",
end:"some date"
mission:[array of mission]
}
```

User Schema:

```
let UserSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: Schema.Types.String,
        required: [true, "name must be required"],
    },
    email: {
        type: Schema.Types.String,
        required: [true, "email must be required"],
        unique: [true, "email already taken"],

    },
    password: {
        type: Schema.Types.String,
        required: true,
        validate: {
            validator: (pass) => pass.length >= 8,
            message: 'password must be consist of 8 characters'
        }
    },
    isAdmin: {
        type: Schema.Types.Boolean,
        default: false
    }
});
```

Mission Schema

```
let MissionSchema = new Schema({
    missionNotes: {
        type: Schema.Types.String,
        required: [true, "name is required"],
        // unique: [true, "must be unique"]
    },
    startDate: {
        type: Schema.Types.Date,
        required: [true, "startDate is required"],
    },
    endDate: {
        type: Schema.Types.Date,
        required: [true, "endDate is required"],

    },
    repeatInterval: {
        type: Schema.Types.Number,
        required: [true, "duration is required"],
    },
    pickupTime: {
        type: Schema.Types.Number,
        required: [true, "pickuptime is required"],
    },//minutes,
    flightNo: {
        type: Schema.Types.String,
        // required: [true, "flightNo is required"],
    },
    who: {
        type: Object,
        required: [true, "who is required"],
    },
    journey: {
        type: Object,
        required: [true, "journey is required"],
    },
    user: {
        type: Object,
        default: null
    },
    isAssign: {
        type: Schema.Types.Boolean,
        default: false,
    },
    info: {
        type: Schema.Types.String,
        // required: [true, "info is required"],
    },
    companyNotes: {
        type: Schema.Types.String
    },
    isCompleted: {
        type: Schema.Types.Boolean,
        default: false
    },
    car: {
        type: Object,
        default: null
    },
    fuel: {
        type: Schema.Types.Number,
        default: 0
    },
    extraExpense: {
        type: Schema.Types.Number,
        default: 0

    },
    crewInfo: {
        type: Schema.Types.String,
        default: ""
    },
    apt: {
        type: Schema.Types.String,
        default: ""
    },//actualpickuptime
    atad: {
        type: Schema.Types.String,
        default: ""
    },//actualtimeatdestination
    adt: {
        type: Schema.Types.String,
        default: ""
    },//actualdrivingtime
    acalpt: {
        type: Schema.Types.String,
        default: ""
    },//actualcalculatedpickuptime
    dap: {
        type: Schema.Types.String,
        default: ""
    },//delayafterpickup
    dacp: {
        type: Schema.Types.String,
        default: ""
    },//delayaftercalcpickup,
    isReminded: {
        type: Schema.Types.Boolean,
        default: false
    },

});
```

Planning Schema

```
let PlanningSchema = new Schema({
    title: {
        type: Schema.Types.String,
        // required: [true, "title is required"],
    },
    start: {
        type: Date,

        required: [true, "start is required"],
    },
    end: {
        type: Date,

        required: [true, "end is required"],

    },
    mission: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'mission' }]


})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this with [MongoDB aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#db.collection.aggregate). 
First get all the planned missions:

```
// You have to be in an async function to await like this
const plan = await Planning.find({ start: { $eq: new Date(Number(data["date"])) } });
const plannedMission = [];
plan.forEach(plan => { plannedMissions = [...plannedMissions, ...plan.mission] });

/* The plannedMission array should be something like this:
 [ "missionId1", "missionId2", "missionId3"]
*/
```

Then, we group missions by users, this is where the aggregation comes in:

```
const pipeline = [ 
  { $match: { '_id': { $in: plannedMissions } } },
  { $group: { _id: "$user._id", missions: { $push: "$$ROOT"}  } }, 
];
// You have to be in an async function to await like this
const result = await db.missions.aggregate(pipeline);

/* result is an array object like this:
  [ 
    { "_id" : userId1, "missions" : ['mission1', 'mission2'] },
    { "_id" : userId2, "missions" : ['mission1', 'mission2'] }
   ] 
*/

// If you want to further reduce the result to just a single object, you can do this:
const missionsByUser = {};

result.forEach(res => userByMission[res._id] = res.missions);

/* missionsByUser should be something like this:
  { 
    "userId1": ['mission1', 'mission2'],
    "userId2": ['mission1', 'mission2'] 
  }
*/
```